# artifact missing: org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.6:Final error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have encountered the "artifact missing: org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.6:Final" error while running my maven+hibernate+spring+cxf application.I have already added hibernate-entitymanager dependency to the pom.xml file:

```
            <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But what result is appeared on the console is as follows:

```
    Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\PFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;.
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Platanus' did not find a matching property.
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-18446"]
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8041"]
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 468 ms
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/PFiles/metadev/tomcat/lib/activemq-all-5.8.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/PFiles/metadev/tomcat/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\PFiles\metadev\ws_kepler_new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5\wtpwebapps\Platanus\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/PFiles/metadev/tomcat/lib/activemq-all-5.8.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/PFiles/metadev/tomcat/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/hibernate-definition-beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:86)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    ... 34 more

Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Platanus] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/Platanus] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Platanus] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-18446"]
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8041"]
Jan 14, 2016 9:57:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1174 ms
```

with the following error on screen:

[image]

How can I resolve this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an IDE issue. From the screenshot, I see you're using eclipse. Right-click on the project and go to Maven -> Update Project...

Also, make sure eclipse has proper access to the internet. Are you behind a firewall or proxy server?

If you're still having issues, try building the project from console. Open a CMD console and run mvn install in the project's root path.

Comment: thanks! updating project seems to solve the problem.